# Revert to before a merged branch

Tags: git

I have my master branch, then I was working on a another feature, merged this to my local master and then pushed this to Github.

Now I need to remove all changes that happened as a result of this merge, until further notice, but be able to merge them back in at a later point in time.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You have to figure out which of the pre-merge commits represents the "mainline", i.e. the part that you want to keep. You can do this using `git log`:

```
commit b556759a560650506da58e59f6a7c6a2c4bcb8f4
Merge: e3dac0d 090ad85
```

... and visual inspection of the two parent commits. (It *appears* that `git merge foo` will always put `HEAD` in the first position of the list of parents and the head of `foo` second, but I'm not sure if this is guaranteed.)

Suppose `e3dac0d` is the mainline, so we want to revert the merging-in of `090ad85`, then that's

```
git revert -m e3dac0d b556759
```

For more details, see the [revert a faulty merge howto](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) by Torvalds and Hamano.

Comment: Also make sure that `090ad85` is still in a branch (or create a new branch on that commit), so it can be retrieved/re-merged later.

Comment: @Arjan: this is a `revert`, not a `reset`, so it can be re-reverted if needed. `090ad85` will stay around in the history.